# Less Middleware with Express

Tags: css, node.js, less

I am trying to setup less on my nodejs project and when i request my page from browser `less-middleware` debug show me wrong path and dest path. When i ask for example `'/public/css/index.css'` from my webpage i adds `'/public/css/'` to the source path. Below are mine configures:

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname+'/server/less',{
    debug: true,
    dest: __dirname+'/public/css',
    once: true
}));
```

And debug screen shows:

```
pathname : /public/css/index.css
source : D\Work\project\server\less\public\css\index.less
destination : D\Work\project\public\css\public\css\index.css
```

Even if i fix the destination path, i am having problem with source and i dont want to put my less files into public folder. Is there a way of remove that `/public/css` from compiled less.
I have tried to add:

```
'preprocess.path': function(pathname, req){
    console.log(pathname);
}
```

but `console.log` never shows. Also perhaps there is a way to not compile every css file users ask and just compile those less files which i have in less folder.
P.S. every module i am using is under `"*"` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was simple enough.

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname+'/server/less/',{
    debug: true,
    dest: __dirname,
    force: true
}));
```

So now in the folder `/server/less` we create folder `public/css` and everything is pulling in right way. Also if we have folder `admin/css` it works too. Trick was to create folders in folder `/server/less`

Answer (score 5):

You might try this (accessing "/css/style.css" within your browser):

```
app.use(lessMiddleware({
  src: __dirname+"/server/less",
  dest: __dirname+"/public/css",
  prefix: "/css",
  // force true recompiles on every request... not the
  // best for production, but fine in debug while working
  // through changes
  force: true,
  debug: true
}));
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and it shows me path.join must be a string,

Comment: I edited the code, removing the spaces before/after the plus signs in both cases.  It sounds like Less is using path.join() behind the scenes and it's not happy with one of the resulting paths.